# Cannot unzip the zip file created using zlib in Java

Tags: java, zip, zlib, unzip

I'm trying to use `zlib` in Java (`java.util.zip`) to zip a file, but cannot unzip the file after creating it. I'm using the code below:

```java
    public static ByteArrayInputStream compress(InputStream inputStream, String targetFilePath) {

        String fileName = new File(targetFilePath).getName();

        try {

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName));
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
            int len;
            while ((len = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                zipOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            bufferedInputStream.close();
            zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            log.error("The file does not exist");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

When I read a `sample.txt` file, and input it as an InputStream to this method, it creates a `sample.zip` file.

However, when I try to open this zip file using `unzip` command, it fails to open with the error below:

```sh
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of sample.zip or
        sample.zip.zip, and cannot find sample.zip.ZIP, period.
```

I tried opening the zip using `jar xvf sample.zip` which worked and showed to contain the `sample.txt` text file. This works because `jar` command does not look for the `End-of-central-directory signature` in the zip file.

Could someone shed some light as to why this signature is not there in the zip file? Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Comment: Does calling `zipOutputStream.close()` after you close the entry fix the problem?

Comment: @dnault that resolved it! :) Thanks a lot. If you post it as an answer, I can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure to close the `ZipOutputStream` after you've written the last entry. This gives the stream a chance to finish creating the ZIP archive.